# postfix disable bounce for transport

Tags: postfix-mta, transport, email-bounces

I have postfix with different transport. For one of these transports I want to disable message **bounce**.

master.cf

```
            smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
            pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
            cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
            qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
            tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
            rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
            bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
            defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
            trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
            verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
            flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
            proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
            proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
            smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
            relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
                -o smtp_fallback_relay=
            showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
            error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
            retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
            discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
            local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
            virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
            lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
dovecot    unix    -    n    n    -    -    pipe
            flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d $(recipient)
emailtransport   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=X user=transpostfix argv=/media/raid1m/mailparse/emailtransport.php

                #****** other options ************
other2emailtransport   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=X user=other2transpostfix argv=/media/raid1m/mailparse/other2emailtransport.php
```

log output:

```
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12110]: connect from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12125]: connect from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/pipe[3893]: 0738C180997: to=<transpostfix@localhost.localhost>, orig_to=<zauri.t@ass.exemple.com.domain>, relay=emailtransport, delay=0.5, delays=0.07/0/0/0.42, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via emailtransport service)
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: 0738C180997: removed
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12110]: setting up TLS connection from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12125]: CC0FF180996: client=client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/smtpd[21657]: disconnect from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:14 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12110]: Anonymous TLS connection established from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128/128 bits)
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12224]: 1662E180997: client=client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/cleanup[20853]: CC0FF180996: message-id=<a779c13adb0ff35fc576b6a9a3a779c7@async.clubggff.com>
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: CC0FF180996: from=<notification+kjdkjivh3i_d@example-mail.com>, size=16051, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12110]: 6873F180998: client=client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/cleanup[21196]: 1662E180997: message-id=<cb01d448de2987547cd69fcab1e92f92@async.clubggff.com>
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/pipe[6928]: CC0FF180996: to=<transpostfix@localhost.localhost>, orig_to=<s01064154705@add3000.exemple.com.domain>, relay=emailtransport, delay=0.97, delays=0.55/0/0/0.42, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via emailtransport service)
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: CC0FF180996: removed
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/cleanup[21201]: 6873F180998: message-id=<1729890133889801-1540059429539540@groups.clubggff.com>
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: 1662E180997: from=<notification+kjdkj5wd1k3_@example-mail.com>, size=18421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 26 15:35:15 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: 6873F180998: from=<notification+kjdkpj3hdv5d@example-mail.com>, size=24947, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/pipe[6941]: 1662E180997: to=<transpostfix@localhost.localhost>, orig_to=<margaretgarza@add3000.exemple.com.domain>, relay=emailtransport, delay=1.4, delays=0.95/0/0/0.41, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via emailtransport service)
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: 1662E180997: removed
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12154]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]: 504 5.5.2 <164.132.109.68>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname; from=<mbeuwen@sfilc.com> to=<t120304677@yahoo.com.tw> proto=SMTP helo=<164.132.109.68>
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12130]: disconnect from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/smtpd[12157]: connect from client=68.ip-11-11-10.eu[11.12.13.14]
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/pipe[6938]: 6873F180998: to=<transpostfix@localhost.localhost>, orig_to=<fgbdfscxw@my-dom.exemple.com.domain>, relay=emailtransport, delay=1, delays=0.58/0/0/0.47, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 255: "/media/raid1m/mailparse/emailtransport.php")
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/cleanup[22236]: 4FFE918099A: message-id=<20160326133516.4FFE918099A@1.444.exemple.com.domain>
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/bounce[10936]: 6873F180998: sender non-delivery notification: 4FFE918099A
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: 4FFE918099A: from=<>, size=27004, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/qmgr[12106]: 6873F180998: removed
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/error[10938]: 4FFE918099A: to=<notification+kjdkpj3hdv5d@example-mail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=delete-lev.exemple.com.domain type=A: Host not found)
```

I need disable **bounce** for **emailtransport**. Some time emailtransport.php give a mistake, but it's exactly does the job I want.

How to turn off any that bounce message to **emailtransport** and so that it did not affect the work or other transports such as **other2emailtransport**

I don't need this:

```
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/pipe[6938]: 6873F180998: to=<transpostfix@localhost.localhost>, orig_to=<fgbdfscxw@my-dom.exemple.com.domain>, relay=emailtransport, delay=1, delays=0.58/0/0/0.47, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 255: "/media/raid1m/mailparse/emailtransport.php")
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/cleanup[22236]: 4FFE918099A: message-id=<20160326133516.4FFE918099A@1.444.exemple.com.domain>
Mar 26 15:35:16 machin1 postfix/bounce[10936]: 6873F180998: sender non-delivery notification: 4FFE918099A
```

After **Command died with status 255** I need delete message 6873F180998. And don't send bound message 4FFE918099A.

Comment: I have the same problem and want to solve it. I don't understand the downvote you received.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem but it does not quite answer my question.

In the documentation is written: http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html

```
DIAGNOSTICS
       Command exit status  codes  are  expected  to  follow  the  conventions
       defined in <sysexits.h>.  Exit status 0 means normal successful comple-
       tion.

       In the case of a non-zero exit status, a limited amount of command out-
       put  is  logged,  and reported in a delivery status notification.  When
       the output begins with a 4.X.X or 5.X.X enhanced status code, the  sta-
       tus  code  takes precedence over the non-zero exit status (Postfix ver-
       sion 2.3 and later).
```

This means I need to have my PHP script gave out `EXIT(0);` I turned on the reporting of errors `ini_set('error_reporting', -1);` and found a problem in script. when I repaired this script error disappeared and the issue resolved.

---

Other theoretical options to think how to solve the problem (but I'm unsure if this is possible):

1. Disable for special postfix transport use bounce
2. Always rewrite error status PHP script to 0
3. edit something in sysexits.h